# AppFabric doesn't show me the persisted instance

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation, appfabric

Hey all, I have one WCF project which creates an instance of a workflow, the workflow after created is persisted and unloaded (then I can resume it using bookmarks). I am using WorkflowApplication.

In the database I can see the record but AppFabric doesn't show me the persisted instance.

Does AppFabric only works for WF xalmx services???

Any help will be appreciated :)

Thanks

Paúl.

Answer (score 1):

Yes AppFabric only shows you information about workflow services it manages. By using the WorkflowApplication you are basically doing all workflow management yourself and keeping AppFabric completely out of the loop. If you want your workflows to show up in AppFabric you should use a workflow service, ie XAMLX file, and use the Receive activity and WCF to work with it.